# Change CSR 4.0 USB BLE Mac Address

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a CSR 4.0 BLE dongle in my desktop. I have tried the below links and all output are as expected. Still the mac remain same..

> Logs I received -  Manufacturer:   Cambridge Silicon Radio (10) Device
>   address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:0A (cyber-blue(HK)Ltd) New BD address:
>   00:1A:7D:DA:71:0B (cyber-blue(HK)Ltd)
>
> Address changed – Reset device now

https://kasiviswanathanblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/change-bluetooth-address/

http://blog.petrilopia.net/linux/change-your-bluetooth-device-mac-address/

is there any other way .. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 as my host .

Comment: Why do you want to change the public bdaddr?

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu (Linux), you can change your Bluetooth public or static address using the btmgmt tool as follows:-

```
sudo btmgmt -i hci0 public-addr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo btmgmt -i hci0 static-addr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

The 'btmgmt' tool replaces the 'hciconfig' tool for configuring the connected Bluetooth hardware, so if your host doesn't have the tool, try installing it or upgrading your Ubuntu to the latest.

More information can be found here:-

- https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/4.3-bluetooth.html
- https://helpmanual.io/help/btmgmt/

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the above commands. Below are the error logs -

Set Public Address for hci0 failed with status 0x0b (Rejected)
Set static address failed with status 0x0b (Rejected)

Comment: you need to power off your device first. Use "sudo btmgmt -i hci0 power off", then do the address setting, then re-enable Bluetooth using "sudo btmgmt -i hci0 power on".

Answer (score 2):

Did you remove the dongle and reinsert it after changing the address? That is what the message wants you to do.

On a CSR-4.0 dongle and Ubuntu 18.04, the btmgmt power off command works but the public-addr fails with status 0x0c (Not Supported) and the static-addr fails with 0x0d (Invalid Parameters) so you do need to compile and run bdaddr from bluez:

```
$ lsusb | fgrep -i bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 064: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    00:1A:7D:DA:71:13
$ mkdir bdaddr
$ cd bdaddr/
$ sudo apt-get source bluez 
[...]
$ sudo apt-get build-dep bluez
[...]
$ ls
bluez-5.48                           bluez_5.48-0ubuntu3.4.dsc
bluez_5.48-0ubuntu3.4.debian.tar.xz  bluez_5.48.orig.tar.xz
$ cd bluez-5.48
$ sudo ./configure --enable-experimental
[...]
$ sudo make
[...]
$ sudo tools/bdaddr | sudo tee -a bluetooth_original_address
Manufacturer:   Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
Device address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13 (cyber-blue(HK)Ltd)
$ uuidgen -r
1aae3392-9f75-4008-ab06-34da97803271
$ sudo tools/bdaddr 01:1A:72:80:32:71
Manufacturer:   Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
Device address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13 (cyber-blue(HK)Ltd)
New BD address: 01:1A:72:80:32:71

Address changed - Reset device now
$ #unplug addapter and plug back in
$ tools/bdaddr 
Manufacturer:   Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
Device address: 01:1A:72:80:32:71
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    01:1A:72:80:32:71
$ sudo install tools/bdaddr /usr/local/bin
```

Note that I only changed the last 6 digits. The first 6 digits identify the manufacturer and are useful to leave the same; but the program will change the first six if you ask it to.  "uuidgen -r" is useful as a source of random digits.

For windows users, there is "Bluetooth MAC address changer for windows".